# Android Login in Portuguese but Locale set to English

Tags: android, facebook

I am working on implementing a Facebook front end into a game that our studio is working on.  Earlier in the week I was getting the proper English language login screen when attempting to log into Facebook, but now the login screen is always showing up in Portuguese.  This is happening on all of our Android devices so it is not an isolated case.  I have changed the language on the login screen to English and my locale is set to en_US but when I get to the application authorization screen it is back in Portuguese.  Does anyone have a suggestion on how I can force it back to the proper language or have insight as to what is going wrong?

Thanks,

Darren

Answer (score 1):

Go to the resource folder and find the values-es etc.
Delete those values folder and select the language from your device in which you want to login.
This is working for me.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug in Facebook.
https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/407246299295529?browse=search_4fb2c58b650061e89267851